# Is the certification process for unbraked wheels and tyres different from braked ones?

Tags: general-aviation

Engineering a landing system for a thing flying with helium. Do unbraked wheels and tyres have a different certification process compared to braked wheels?

Comment: If you're talking about aircraft certification, isn't it kind of necessary for us to know what jurisdiction your aircraft falls under?